# Subresource Integrity With Angular-Cli

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

I was wondering if anyone knew of a possible way to activate Subresource Integrety with Angular-Cli. According to the following link: [GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/5841/files) It would be a feature (or a future feature). I was hoping to activate it but it does not seem to be active on the current versions. Is there another way to use Subresource Integrety with Angular-Cli?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass the `--subresource-integrity` flag into your ng build command.

You can verify that it works by looking at your index.html file. You'll see the *integrity* attribute on linked stylesheets and scripts.

SRI requires v1.5.0+ of the CLI.

E.G. `ng build --subresource-integrity`

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to test this soon so if anyone has success with this solution please let me know so I can mark this as the answer :).

Comment: `--subresource-integrity` flag is only available for the build command, not serve

Comment: I feel like it used to work on a serve command. Maybe it did when I wrote the answer. But when I try it now the CLI puts a note in the console that it ignores that SRI flag. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: That is true for just about everything in the modern web. If possible, I recommending encouraging your customers, users, and/or management to stop using or supporting IE. (Good luck.)

Answer (score 0):

Now we can simply add `"subresourceIntegrity": true` in `production` `configurations` in `angular.json` file